# Trocar cor de fundo e texto de item em GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Tenho um `GridView` com vários números e tenho um evento de click nos itens deste `GridView`.
Gostaria de que os itens que já foram clicados troque as cores de fundo e do texto, para mostrar ao usuário que já foram clicados.
Se possível desabilitar para futuros cliques.

O evento é este:

```
private void dataGridNumbers_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedNumber = dataGridNumbers.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if (selectedNumber == resposta)
    {
        txtBoxInfo.Text = "Congratulations! You Find the Ramdon Number!";
    }
    if (selectedNumber != resposta)
    {
        numbersCloser(Int32.Parse(selectedNumber));
    }
}
```

Comment: Desculpe, estou no Mexico e havia feito a pergunta no stack em espanhol e nao me responderam nada de util! Meu teclado é espanhol e nao tem todos caracteres para escrever bem em portuges.

Comment: Estou criando para publicar na tenda do Windows 10, nao é asp.net!

Comment: Teclados em espanhol têm todos os acentos que o português utiliza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use o evento** `dataGridNumbers_CellClick`

```
private void dataGridNumbers_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen;
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
}
```

**UWP**

```
GridView.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
```

Comment: Cassio, na verdade nao é dataGridView, em UWP só tem Grid View! Tentei usar o codigo que colocasse de exemplo, porem o Grid View nao tem opcao de Rows. Obrigado de todas maneiras.

Comment: alterei o código

Comment: Obrigado, vou fazer um teste aqui e te informo.

Comment: Coloquei dessa forma: dataGridNumbers.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red); porem me troca a cor de todo GridView, nao apenas da area ocupada pelo item que foi clicado! Nao encontrei a forma de colocar SelectedItem ou algo do genero para a troca de Background!

Comment: use a função GetRow para pegar a linha, e depois mude a cor